# Akka-streams mapConcat not working with cycled RunnableGraph

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have `RunnableGraph` like following. When there is simple `map` between `broadcast` and `merge` stages everything is fine. However, when it comes to `mapConcat`, this code is not working after consuming the first element.

I want to know why it doesn't work.

```
RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
import GraphDSL.Implicits._

val M = b.add(MergePreferred[Int](1))
val B = b.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
val S = Source(List(3))

S ~> M ~> Flow[Int].map { s => println(s); s } ~> B ~> Sink.ignore
M.preferred <~ Flow[Int].map(x => List.fill(3)(x-1)).mapConcat(x => {println(x); x}).filter(_ > 0)  <~ B
ClosedShape 
}) 

// run() output: 
// 3
// List(2,2,2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mapConcat` stage blocks the feedback loop, and that is expected. Consider the following chain of events:

1. the `mapConcat` function prints `List(2,2,2)`
2. the `mapConcat` stage needs demand to emit the first of the 3 available elements (2, 2, 2)
3. the demand has to come from the Merge stage, and therefore from the Broadcast stage.
4. the Broadcast stage backpressures if any of its downstreams backpressures. It's downstreams are a `Sink.ignore` (that never backpressures), and the `mapConcat` itself.
5. the `mapConcat` backpressures if "there are still remaining elements from the previously calculated collection", as per the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#mapconcat). This is indeed the case.

In other words, your cycle is unbalanced. You are introducing more elements in the feedback loop than you are removing.

This issue is explained in detail in [this documentation page](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-graphs.html#graph-cycles-liveness-and-deadlocks), where a couple of solutions are also presented. For your specific case, because of the filter stage you have, introducing a buffer larger than *13* would print all the elements. However, note that the graph will just hang and not complete afterwards.

```
S ~> M ~> Flow[Int].map { s => println(s); s } ~> B ~> Sink.ignore
M.preferred <~ Flow[Int].buffer(20, OverflowStrategy.dropHead) <~ Flow[Int].map(x => List.fill(3)(x-1)).mapConcat(x => {println(x); x}).filter(_ > 0)  <~ B
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is really helpful! After your explanation I find out that `conflateWithSeed` is more suitable in my situation as I don't want to lose messages on overflow.